# Cannot find Common Tools for Visual C++ 2017

Tags: visual-c++, installation, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio Professional 2017, and the project I'm using requires Common Tools for Visual C++, which I don't have installed.

However, I can't find it on the Visual Studio 2017 installer nor the Microsoft official website. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be a directory path like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools"`?

Comment: *Common Tools for Visual C++* was a selection the VS 2015 installer. For VS 2017, you just need to select one of the C++ workloads like "Desktop Development with C++", "Game development with C++", or the optional feature *C++ Universal Windows Platform tools* with the "Universal Windows Platform development" workload.

Comment: You are correct, Chuck. I was missing Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015, not 2017. Thanks!

Comment: @NaBUru38, Do you mean that you have resolved this issue? If so, would you mind sharing your solution as an answer for this issue and then accept it as the answer? If you get any other VS setup issue, please also free free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chuck Walbourn said, Common Tools for Visual C++ does not exist for Visual Studio 2017. The component that I was missing was Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015.

Answer (score 0):

[Get the VS 2017 installer here](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202017&wt.mc_id=o%7Emsft%7Evscom%7Eolder-downloads). You can get the "Trial" versions of Professional or Enterprise and then upgrade them to full versions with your license key.

And get [other VS installers here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/).